# Add custom cell in childViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cells, childviewcontroller

I have a `childViewController` on a `UICollectionViewController`. I have so my childViewController appears on the screen. But when I register a cell `collectionView?.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellId)` and use `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAt`. The problem is that the cells wont appear, I have checked the code so it´s right. Can it be something with the childViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's not preferred to add any child view or viewController to **UICollectionViewController** or **UITableViewController** as you will see un-expected results as both of them inherits from **scrollview** and make the added content scroll able or scattered any place, if you have then better create a custom viewController with a **collectionView** and the **childViewController**